# Loop array of object and form an insert

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array.

```
    var res= [{
        "MATNR": "4",
        "TYPES": [{
            "KSCHL": "PR00",
            "KBETR": "12.000"
        }, {
            "KSCHL": "K005",
            "KBETR": "-10.000"
        }]
    },
    {
        "MATNR": "5",
        "TYPES": [{
            "KSCHL": "PR00",
            "KBETR": "12.000"
        }, {
            "KSCHL": "K005",
            "KBETR": "-10.000"
        }]
    }
]
```

Code for process the array

```
let insert ='INSERT INTO T VALUES ('
res.forEach((values)=> 
Object.keys(values).forEach(function (item) {
    insert =insert+item.MATNR+','+item.KBETR
}) 

);
```

I have to form an insert statement

```
INSERT INTO T VALUES(4,12.00,-10.00)
INSERT INTO T VALUES(5,12.00,-8.00)
```

I tried the looping but not getting the desired result.

Comment: Can you please fix your object syntax?

Comment: Is your desired output an array of two strings (ie both insert statements)? Or one string containing both insert statements?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` method with some template literals to return one string as a result.

```js
var res = [{"MATNR":"4","TYPES":[{"KSCHL":"PR00","KBETR":"12.000"},{"KSCHL":"K005","KBETR":"-10.000"}]},{"MATNR":"5","TYPES":[{"KSCHL":"PR00","KBETR":"12.000"},{"KSCHL":"K005","KBETR":"-10.000"}]}]

const string = res.map(({MATNR, TYPES}) => {
  const types = TYPES.map(({KBETR}) => KBETR).join(',')
  return `INSERT INTO T VALUES(${MATNR},${types})`
}).join("\n")

console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate through res.forEach(values => ..), each "value" is an object like `{ MATNR: SOME_NUMBER, TYPES: [array of objects with keys "KSCHL" and "KBETR"] }`.

Doing `Object.keys(values)` would thus not give you access to the the MATNR and KBETR fields at once. To get the KBETR part, you would need to check the TYPES field.

For future references, please format the code before posting so it's more readable for others. :)